# Python classes that create each others' class objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with Python UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735263/help-with-python-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

In python3, I have two classes, one for DNA and one for RNA.  I would like the DNA class to have a method that takes the DNA sequence (an instance variable of DNA, self.sequence), changes it into an RNA sequence (easily done with a for loop), and then creates an RNA object with the new sequence as an instance variable.

At the same time, I would like the RNA class to have a method that does the opposite (That is, it takes the RNA sequence, produces a corresponding DNA sequence, and then creates a DNA object that uses the sequence as an instance variable.)

My method for making RNA from DNA is as follows:

```
def transcribe(self):
    RNAseq=''
    for base in self.sequence:
        if base=='A' or base=='C' or base=='G':
            RNAseq=RNAseq+base
        if base=='T':
            RNAseq=RNAseq+'U'
    RNA=RNA(RNAseq,self.name+'RNA')
    return RNA
```

This code gives me the error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'RNA' referenced before assignment

Can what I want to do be done?

Comment: Is `RNA` the name of your RNA class?

Answer (score 5):

Call your variable something other than `RNA`, e.g. `rna`:

```
rna = RNA(RNAseq, self.name + 'RNA')
return rna
```

Otherwise you're trying to use the same name for two different things, the class and the variable, and the latter shadows the former.

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  I feel a little silly now, but lesson learned!

Comment: @user1884604: No need to feel silly. That error message isn't terribly clear.